Terrible face recognition skills: how to improve
I've this problem where I am terrible at recognising faces. This gets embarassing when at conferences etc. people recognise me but I have no clue who they are or have even met before.
Is there any way to get better at this? Just looking for tips from others.
Sometimes I meet someone in the morning session at a conference and reintroduce myself at the dinner meeting.
Any tips?

Is this a new issue for you, have you had it all your life, etc.? And if it’s not new, what coping techniques have you used?

Is this specific to academics, or do you have trouble recognising people in general?

I’m voting to close this question because it should be on https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

In my mind, I sort people into buckets. When I see someone who looks like a Jennifer, I call her a Jennifer

@AgnishomChattopadhyay I do the same thing with people who look like Agnishom

@Ben could you assist in moving the question to the other forum? Just closing it would be a shame.

@curious_cat: I'm not an administrator/moderator of this site, so have no ability to move questions.  I'm not sure if the moderators can even do this.

This is actually a recognized disorder. If accurate, the linked article indicates there is no cure, but active research. But seeing a medical professional might give you some hints.
Making and reviewing notes about important people you meet (professors, for example) might help, though I have no evidence.
A search online for "face blindness" or Prosopagnosia, might turn up some things that work.
Depending on your location, you might be able to participate in that research.
Wikipedia has more, including a list of some famous people who suffer from this.

Oliver Sacks, the famous neurologist and academic, was famously face blind and wrote about it in The New Yorker in 2010: https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2010/08/30/face-blind

Thanks everyone for the excellent answers! Too bad my question got closed but just want everyone to know that your answers helped me a lot. I'm trying to verify if the diagnosis matches me and to figure out coping strategies from the excellent advice given on this thread.

As Buffy mentioned, this sounds more like face-blindness (prosopagnosia) than "bad with faces." You should see about getting evaluated for this disorder - if you do in fact have it, and are comfortable sharing that with others, simply saying "hey, I'm sorry, I have face-blindness, can you tell me who you are" will get you through most of these interactions. (And even if you don't have face-blindness, many people will be understanding of "I am so sorry, but I am really, really bad with faces - can you please tell me your name again?")
Other strategies include paying attention to what people are wearing, rather than what they look like, to identify them later in the day, which may help you even if you don't have face-blindness.

The best way to avoid embarrassment is to simply stop being embarrassed about something you should never be embarrassed about in the first place!
I have moderate face-blindness and I can attest that by far the biggest recognition challenges I have in life are indeed at academic conferences where the total amount of interesting information coming at me per unit time is so high.
@WhatTheDuck's answer describes what I do - I'm up front about difficulty with faces. If someone thinks it's weird or I'm weird or it means I'm stupid, then I really don't want to interact with them further anyway - screw 'em!
Most folks have heard of face-blindness or are at least open to the idea or have met someone who has "trouble with faces" or may have it themselves, and have been quite accommodating.
As soon as I do remember something (it's usually something academic or technical from the previous interaction) I blurt it out to reassure I recognize them in some way and valued our previous interaction. "Oh, you're the one with the spin-orbit splitting problem!" or similar.
My choice has been to accept my condition, embrace it, and be comfortable with it, and let others carry some of the load by helping remind me how we last interacted. As long as I remain cheerful, positive, engaging and interested in finding out who the heck they are, most folks have no problem with it.

I wanted to add to and emphasize the other excellent answers already here. (I'm a human vision / visual neuroscientist whose research is very adjacent to prosopagnosia and who has worked with scientists who study prosopagnosia in the past.)
Prosopagnosia is not only a real thing, but—in my personal experience—very common in academia. The article linked by Buffy estimates an occurrence of 2%, which I can't contest as a measurement of the general population. But among vision scientists (who are pretty likely to know whether they have prosopagnosia or not), I would estimate the fraction to be much higher. (Of course, vision scientists may not be an unbiased sample.)
The last time I looked into it, one of the leading theories on prosopagnosia has to do with the organization of neurons in the areas of the brain responsible for face recognition. An individual neuron in the visual cortex will typically integrate information across a contained region of space in the visual field—or, in other word, each neuron "sees" a patch, e.g. a disk, of your vision. In the face recognition regions of individuals without face blindness, these neurons are typically wired to receive input from regions that are large enough to contain an entire face or a large region of a face, allowing those neurons to form a wholistic representation of any face they "see." In individuals with poor face recognition, these neurons are wired to receive input from much smaller areas, preventing them from ever getting a full picture of a face. For those interested, see Withoft et al., (2016).
To be clear, this is not settled theory, I'm not an expert, and I don't have any particular reason to believe that there is a single cause for all cases of prosopagnosia, but I share the above hypothesis to illustrate that the people who study face perception (1) absolutely believe this is a real thing that varies in the brains of individuals, (2) absolutely don't believe that people who struggle with face perception do so because of some lack of empathy with others or some inability to care about other people or their faces. In my experience a lot of people who struggle with face perception feel a lot of guilt about whether they are trying hard enough to remember others or whether they are subconsciously dismissing people, and you should not feel guilty about that.
Colleagues of mine who deal with this struggle sometimes have strategies for it. Some find it much easier to recognize people by their voice, others find individual features like hairstyle/jewelry/facial hair to be sufficient. My sense is that not all individuals with face blindness have the same difficulties, so YMMV. (And as mentioned in other answers, you can likely find much more of this information elsewhere online.)
In my community of vision science there is not much stigma about prosopagnosia due to broad awareness, so again YMMV, but I'd also add that most academics I know who are up-front about their struggles with faces get a lot of empathy and support from their colleagues.
